# How to make Passwords more secure in Magento Community Edition?

Tags: security, magento

How can I make magento to store passwords with better encryption.Since md5 is not robust one.
Is there an way to increase security in magento?

So the customer details are secure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the magento encryption algorithm from your custom one. I'm using SHA1 for my mageto. i have created a custom module for that.Inside the hash function you can implement your any of algorithm.

magento/app/code/local/My/ShaModule/Model/Encryption.php

```
   public function getHash($password, $salt = false)
    {
        return $this->hash($password);
    }
   public function hash($data){


        return sha1($data); 
    }

    public function validateHash($password, $hash) {
        return $this->hash($password) === $hash;

        }
}
?>
```

magento/app/code/local/My/ShaModule/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!--
    Document   : config.xml
    Created on : July 26, 2012, 1:12 PM
    Author     : sanjeewani
    Description:
        Purpose of the document follows.
-->

<config>
    <modules>
        <My_ShaModule>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
            <depends>
             <Mage_Core />
            </depends>
        </My_ShaModule>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <models>
            <core>
                <rewrite>
                 <encryption>My_ShaModule_Model_Encryption</encryption>
                </rewrite>
            </core>
        </models>
        <helpers>
            <core>
             <encryption_model>My_ShaModule_Model_Encryption</encryption_model>
            </core>
        </helpers>
    </global>

    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <my_shamodule>
             <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>My_ShaModule</module>
                    <frontName>shamodule</frontName>
                </args>
            </my_shamodule>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to a good blog on this:

http://www.magentogarden.com/blog/how-are-passwords-encrypted-in-magento.html

It uses the same MD5, but has a slat of additional security attached to it.

Comment: Thanks for you reply,it was helpful to understand magento password encryption.ButI need some more details to implement better security

Comment: The on that Magento has is quite secured. and if you use the Salt as mentioned in the link.. it is then a better security.

Comment: I think @Muk is asking like how to get EE level password encryption.  I know that EE uses a different algorithm.

Comment: @sparcksoft Yes I want to get EE level password encryption.

Comment: Have you checked what licensing / copyright restrictions would be in place if you were to attempt to use the same algorithm as what EE uses?  I'm not sure if there would be any restrictions.  Perhaps it's a freely available encryption algorithm.